# hbase: regionserver is automatically shutdown

Tags: hbase

I have my hbase installed and running on a single node local mode at the moment.

For unknown reason, I can start regionserver but it will be shutdown automatically and rightaway.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I did not make any configuration in hbase-site.xml

I can still start the hbase shell as below:
[image]

How can I get this fixed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: attach the hBase logs.. Seems HBase shell works fine if no services are running. it throws exception only you perform operation on the HBase. !! better you can attach logs, if not start individually and update the logs ..

Answer (score 0):

**There's nothing to fix.**
If you check the content of `/opt/hadoop/hbase/logs/hbase-root-regionserver-xie1.log`, you will found logs like bellow:

```
Not starting a distinct region server because hbase.cluster.distributed is false
```

In hbase standalone mode, the process `HMaster` will provide the service.
You can just run `bin/start-hbase.sh` to start the service.